# Static library and NSNotification in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, static-libraries

I have created a library which helps to track wifi status.I have a notification which is called whenever wifi switch is on or off, usually i write this piece of code on client(application),but now i have to include this notification too in the library.

For this i have created a new file which is derived from NSObject and created a function in that including the notification and the selector method in that file.

When i call the function from Application it gets called only once and switching on of off the wifi doesn't reflect that function. How and where should i write this notification so that it gets reflected.

> I am adding code files  for above discription can u please tell me where am i going wrong?
>   the link is: http://snk.to/f-cdpav3fn

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an observer for some general properties like connectivity in your case, you should to create this observer in your application delegate, when you enter for first time or when you enter from background and remove it when you enter in background. If you need to finish any operation when you enter in background like save data, finish synchronization... you should to remove your observer after to finish these operations